# Array of Pointers Pointing to an unknown location

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, output, cout

I was practicing with array of pointers.
i wrote a simple **code.**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a[3]={1,2,3};
    int *b[3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        b[i] = &a[i];
    }

    cout<<b; //This gives a confusing output
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout<<b[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

and **Output** is

```
0x6ffe10
0x6ffe30
0x6ffe34
0x6ffe38
```

Now I don't understand where the b pointing.
I know this sounds weird but i wanna know.
where the b pointer pointing.
The b[0], b[1], b[2] gives expected result.

Comment: what did you expect `b` to be?

Comment: It was just an experiment. 
I searched on Internet to find something about it.
but in vain .
so i posted it here.

Comment: so what is the result of `cout<<b` and why do you think it is confusing?

Comment: I wanna know what b pointing in Memory.
I mean what is inside address b.

Comment: `b` is not a pointer, it's an array. Read about arrays decaying into pointers to their first element in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` is an *array of pointers to* `int`. It's address is the *address of the first pointer*.

- The first pointer `b[0]` is assigned the *address of* element `a[0]` (so `b[0]` points to `1`).
- `b[1]` is assigned the *address of* `a[1]` (so `b[1]` points to `2`)
- `b[2]` is assigned the *address of* `a[2]` (so `b[2]` points to `3`)

In each case the pointer in the `b` array holds the address of the corresponding element within `a`. So if there are any changes made to the elements of `a` after your loop assigning the address in `a` to `b`, the value held in the memory location pointed to by the element of `b` will change, but the address for that value held by `b` will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

`b` is an array of pointers to `int` which is a local variable on the stack.

Its address does not depend on what individual elements of its array are assigned to.

If you print its value **before** the `for` loop (where you assign values to its members), you will see that it is the same as the value printed **after** the `for` loop.

See live demo [here](http://cpp.sh/5wds6).

Pictorially:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When `b` is passed to `cout`'s `<<` operator, it decays into a pointer; hence as far as the printing function is concerned, printing out `b` is the same as printing out `&b[0]`.

Therefore, `cout << b;` prints out the address of the first pointer in the `b[3]` array.  (Note that the address of the pointer is *not* the same thing as the address the pointer is pointing to!  That can be a source of confusion -- just keep in mind that a pointer-variable is a variable as well, and like any other variable, it has its own unique location in memory, which is distinct from the location it is pointing at)

Comment: It may be logically equivalent in the context of pointer decay, but generally arrays are distinct types from pointers

Answer (score 2):

b Memory adress of the whole array.

Comment: I guess the address of array is the 0 index of array .
but this address is 20 bytes ahead of that . . .

Comment: If you look at the size of b you will see that it will be the size of the 3 integers. It is the whole container. (And yes i understand what you mean... )

Comment: Don't forget there are *two* arrays in the program; `a` and `b`.  The `a` array starts at `0x6ffe30` and is 12 bytes long (3 4-byte ints), whereas the `b` array starts at `0x6ffe10` and is 24 bytes long (3 8-byte pointers)